# wp_posts is missing the text?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to edit my wordpress site (with berlin theme) , and after editing some text, tried to publish without success (page stays with old text)
I thought I would overcome the issue by updating directly in db the ws_posts table, but I can't see to find the records that contains the text.

Any idea where I can find a text that appears in one of my pages but not in wp_posts (also tried other tables, didn't find anything regarding that)

Is there some file on the FS? maybe some other methods of WP to store text?

Comment: when you clicked publish, what happened exactly? Any errors on page? Any errors in console? Very vague description of your problem.

Comment: Nothing happens.. it looks like it's being published. directing me to the published page without any errors. no console errors as well.

Comment: check if its preview working or not?

Comment: would you say you have a lot of custom fields on it? There might be a server limitation on the post_max_size

Comment: Preview is the same, redirects me to the same content..  that's the main reason I wanted to solve it from the DB and didn't find the text.. I've upgraded to latest WP ( i thought that might be the issue) . and No custom fields at all..

Comment: Are you using a caching plugin?

Comment: No.. during my search for that issue/problem, I can across posts related to such plugins (I wasn't familiar with that btw) . I've checked the plugins, none is related to cache.

Answer (score 0):

After doing a lot of diggin in the DB, (and I'm hardly a WP expert) I found the text in the wp_postmeta table, formatted with something related to the theme (pojo something)